# React: Warning: validateDOMNesting(...): Whitespace text nodes cannot appear as a child of <tr>

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, reactjs, validation

So I have this error popping up about the spaces left in . I am trying to find an answer in stack but I don't actually have a  or any table element in my project because I am using React and Material-UI.
I also get another similar error like this:

```
Warning: validateDOMNesting(...): <td> cannot appear as a child of <tfoot>.
```

which again I cannot find any  or  in my project. My error tab is filled and every error has one same dependency which is:

> js/0.chunk.js:227830:31

Comment: Are you importing any third-party modules that *might* be using a table element? If you search for `<td>` in your DOM tree, what do you find?

Comment: @Titulum no Idea, maybe it's Material-UI components that's all I have downloaded.

Comment: Could you check if somewhere in your code there is whitespace around one of you values, like so: `<any-tag> {code} </any-tag>`, and remove the whitespace, like so: `<any-tag>{code}</any-tag>`?

Comment: @Titulum Yes I have A TON now that I am checking. Isn't there any easy fix to this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that React is complaining about whitespace around curly brackets in JSX tags. Somewhere, one of those JSX tags is actually a `<td>` tag, but because it's a third-party element you can't easily see what tag it is behind the scenes.

So you will have to change all following code:

```js
<tag> {code} </tag>
```

to

```js
<tag>{code}</tag>
```

The easiest way to fix this would be to do a global replace in all files with a JSX file extension:

- `> {` to `>{`
- `} </` to `}</`

But that's quite prone to breaking because it could be valid code in some places.

I'm not sure whether there is an ESlint rule for catching these issues during development.